# Using re.search in Python Regex to separate x and y coordinates

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have the following segment of LaTex Code:

```
  & $(-1,1)$
  & $(0,\infty)$
```

How would I use regex in python in order to separate out the coordinate pair into its x and y components? I want to use re.search for this.

For example, for the above segment I would want to receive:

```
x: -1 y: 1
x: 0 y: \infty
```

Currently I am using:

```
c = map(str,re.findall(r'-?\S',range))
a = c[1]
b = c[3]
```

However this only matches integers and not the "\infty" 's I need.

Thank you.

Comment: You clearly have an idea of where to start. Here (https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) is an overview of regular expressions: I suggest you look there and start coding. If you really can't figure out why you're not making headway, post back here with your specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
import re

lines = '''  & $(-1,1)$
  & $(0,\infty)$ '''

matches = re.findall(r'\((.*),(.*)\)', lines)

for (a,b) in matches:
    print "x: %s  y: %s" % (a,b)
```

Outputs

```
x: -1  y: 1
x: 0  y: \infty
```

If you catch some weirdness, consider replacing `*` with `*?` to make the matching "not greedy".